# Using the method of characteristics for a first-order nonhomogeneous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem solving the following nonhomogeneous problem using the method of characteristics:

$u_t+u_x=x ,\space x \in R, \space t>0$

$u(x,0)=\phi(x), \space x \in R$

The characteristics can then be found to be:

$x(t)=x_0+t$

Along this characteristic we have the following:

$\frac{du(x(t),t)}{dt}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=x$

In order to find $u(x(t),t)$, the below equation has to be integrated:

$\frac{du(x(t),t)}{dt}=x$

$\therefore \text{Equation 1:}  \int du(x(t),t)=\int x(t)dt$

By substituting $t$ with $k$, the below equation is equivalent to the above, only that $t$ has been substituted with $k$:

$\int_{0}^{t} du(x(k),k)=\int_{0}^{t} x(k)dk$

I do understand that the left side of this equation becomes

$u(x(t),t)-\phi(x_0)$, but my problem is that I have a problem solving the integral to right side of the equation above since we are supposed to integrate a variable x which is dependent on $t$ times $dt$. The solution should be the following:

$\text{Equation 2: } u(x(t),t)=\phi(x_0)+x_0t+\frac{1}{2}t^2$

Can anyone help me to get from equation 1 to equation 2, and how we integrate $\int_{0}^{t} x(k)dk$? (If it was $\int_{0}^{t} xdx$, I know how to solve it, but the fact that we use $dk$ instead of $dx$ makes me unsure how to solve it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not answer your question exactly, but shows how to solve the equation. The general solution will be the sum of the general solution of the homogeneius equation and a particular solution of the completa equation. The general solution of the homogeneous equation is esasily found to be $\phi(x-t)$ for an arbitrary function $\phi$. By inspecton, we see that a particular solution of the complete equation is $x^2/2$. Thus, the general solution is 
$$
u(x,t)=\phi(x-t)+\frac{x^2}{2}.
$$
Setting $t=0$ and using the initial condition we find that
$$
\phi(x)=\psi(x)-\frac{x^2}{2}.
$$
and
$$
u(x,t)=\psi(x-t)+t\,x-\frac{t^2}{2}.
$$

Comment: Okay, thank you for your reply.